# Transform training data into array in Neural network

Tags: neural-network, deeplearning4j

I am trying a time prediction model in deeplearning4j for text processing which takes no of words,sentences,char as input features and produces time as output.But while modelling input data to output i am having difficulties to transform these values and how to tell the network for these values of input these are respective output values.

Also should i reduce dimensionality from just having x1 and y.instead of x1-x4?

training-data.csv has the below columns with 100 values.
x1,x2,x3,x4(inputs) y(output)

I tried using SequenceRecorder and Iterator which can capture variant inputs.
below is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    // Initlizing parametres
    final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainExpert.class);
    final int seed =123;
    final int numInput = 4;
    final int numOutput = 1;
    final int numHidden = 20;
    final double learningRate = 0.015;
    final int batchSize =30;
    final int nEpochs =30;
    //final int inputFeatures =4;

    //Constructing Training data

    final File baseFolder =new File("/home/aj/my/samples/corpus");
    final File testFolder = new File("/home/aj/my/samples/corpus/train_data_0.csv");
    SequenceRecordReader trainReader = new CSVSequenceRecordReader(0,",");
    trainReader.initialize(new NumberedFileInputSplit(baseFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/train_data_%d.csv",0,0));
    DataSetIterator trainIterator = new SequenceRecordReaderDataSetIterator(trainReader,batchSize,-1,4,true);


    SequenceRecordReader testReader = new CSVSequenceRecordReader(0,",");
    testReader.initialize(new NumberedFileInputSplit(baseFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "/test_data_%d.csv",0,0));
    DataSetIterator testIterator = new SequenceRecordReaderDataSetIterator(testReader,batchSize,-1,4,true);

    DataSet trainData = trainIterator.next();
    System.out.println(trainData);
    DataSet testData = testIterator.next();

    NormalizerMinMaxScaler normalizer = new NormalizerMinMaxScaler(0, 1);
    normalizer.fitLabel(true);
    normalizer.fit(trainData);              
    normalizer.transform(trainData);
    normalizer.transform(testData);

    //Configuring Network
    log.info("Building Model");
    MultiLayerConfiguration config = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .seed(seed)
            .iterations(1)
            .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT)
            .learningRate(learningRate)
            .updater(Updater.NESTEROVS).momentum(0.9)
            .list()
            .layer(0, new DenseLayer.Builder()
                    .nIn(numInput)
                    .nOut(numHidden)
                    .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER).
                    activation(Activation.RELU)
                    .build())
            .layer(1, new DenseLayer.Builder()
                    .nIn(numHidden)
                    .nOut(numHidden)
                    .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                    .activation(Activation.RELU)
                    .build())
            .layer(2, new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunction.MSE)
                    .nIn(numHidden)
                    .nOut(numOutput)
                    .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
                    .activation(Activation.IDENTITY)
                    .build())
            .pretrain(false).backprop(true).build();

    //Initializing network
    log.info("initlizing model");
    MultiLayerNetwork model = new MultiLayerNetwork(config);
    model.init();
    model.setListeners(new ScoreIterationListener(1));

    log.info("Training Model");
    for(int i=0;i<nEpochs;i++)
    {
        model.fit(trainData);
    }
    //Evaluation
    RegressionEvaluation reval=new RegressionEvaluation(1);

        while(testIterator.hasNext())
        {
    INDArray feat =testData.getFeatureMatrix();
    INDArray labels =testData.getLabels();
    INDArray prediction =model.output(feat);
    reval.eval(labels, prediction);
}
    System.out.println(reval.stats());
}
```

}

my data has four input values and one output values.
But i get an exception
 `org.deeplearning4j.exception.DL4JInvalidInputException: Input that is not a matrix; expected matrix (rank 2), got rank 3 array with shape [1, 4, 107]`

Answer (score 0):

We have an end to end csv classifier example here: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/recurrent/seqClassification/UCISequenceClassificationExample.java
 An rnn can handle multi variate input. In fact I encourage it. Having only 1 input feature doesn't do much for you.
I don't see the need to reduce it down to x1 and y.